# jQuery: how to control the contents of one div by clicking on a set of other divs

Tags: jquery

I have been reading through stackoverflow most of the day because I am building an image gallery and I would like to have a nested set of thumbnail divs control via the mouse click a larger div which is sitting above the thumbnails. I want to use jQuery rather than iFrames, but I'm stuck.  Currently I have the following script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#div_2').hide();

$("#mybutton1").click(function(){
$("#div_1").fadeOut(1000, function(){
$("#div_2").fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
$("#mybutton2").click(function(){
$("#div_2").fadeOut(1000, function(){
$("#div_1").fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

The challenge for me in moving forward is that I would like whatever thumbnail is clicked to load the larger version of that image into the preview area.  If I have 10 thumbnails, I cannot have each one fade out all the others that might be there, but rather, I would like to concatenate the code so that whatever image is there will fade out and the larger version of the thumbnail that is clicked on will fade in.

I have thought of linking the thumbnails to the larger preview images and then disabling standard link behavior with the following function:

```
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then I thought I could incorporate the following, though I'm not sure how to fully implement it:

```
$('.gallery_preview').html('<a style="background-image:url('+photo_preview+');"></a>');
```

One of the threads that asked a similar question to mine I found interesting, but I was unable to fully understand how it worked:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420033/1422589

Also, without using .hide, how is it possible to load div's dynamically that aren't on the page?

Lots of questions, I know --any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var bigImageLink = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#div_1").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", bigImageLink).fadeIn(1000); 
    });
});
```

Make sure the `href` in your thumbnail links has the direct link to the large image version, and that `#div_1` has just one `img` tag inside.

Comment: I Tried OhMrBigShot's code and immediately following the fadeOut, #div1 vanishes and my .gallery_thumbnails shoots up to the top to replace where #div1 was (and where the new bigImageLink should fadeIn)...

Comment: As a fix to the above problem, I have nested #div1 inside a slightly bigger div so that now the css doesn't change, but still my #div1 fades out and is thereafter entirely gone so no big images load.

Comment: @llyfre, sorry, you can change the `fadeOut` to a `fadeTo` - like this: `.fadeTo(duration, opacity[, callback])`

Comment: Thanks Ahren, I tried a FadeTo :

var bigImageLink = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#div_1").fadeTo(4000, .5, function(){
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", bigImageLink).fadeIn(1000);

 --Seems the problem is that the callback isn't happening after the animation.

Comment: have you tried an `alert()` or a `console.log()` in the callback to test to make sure it fires?

Comment: I tried an alert() in the callback and it definitely fires!  It's that dag-gone function that simply isn't right.  I know I'm close, but somethings not quite right...

Comment: Alright - try calling an `alert()` or `console.log()` and alerting the value of `bigImageLink`. If that's fine, test `$(this)` is scoped correctly.

Comment: I have uploaded the files so you can see how it is running.  As it stands, the fade to .5 works and the bigImageLink brings in the images via the href, however the fade in isn't working properly and the new images are only visible at all because the fadeTo is set to .5 and not 0.  Here's the link [link]http://moutonotopia.com/talkingDivsTEST/talkingDivs.html

Comment: change your `fadeIn()` to `fadeTo(1000,1)`

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the variable BigImageLink is fading out the div #preview that is also supposed to fade in the other image.  If the variable's fadeTo =.5, then the fade in will be limited to .5 too, if the fadeTo is 0 then the fade in will be 0.  Is there some way to effectively clear the div #preview after it fades to 0 in order that the next image that fades in will not be dependent on #preview's current opacity?

Comment: aaah, stupid me. Sorry. Before you do `.fadeIn(1000)`, call `.end()`. so: `$(this).find("img").attr("src", bigImageLink).end().fadeIn(1000); `

Comment: Ahren, Brilliant!  I changed the very end of your code to fadeTo(1000,1); and the whole thing finally works like a charm -Whew!  Thanks a million for all you help, I've learned a ton!  Best, llyfre